# jsGrid is not working correctly with data loading page by page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsgrid

I am trying to get [jsGrid](http://js-grid.com) working in a project but I am missing something since I can't make it to work correctly. I have read docs carefully several times.

The scenario is as follow:

- An AJAX call for get a list of subregion
- An AJAX call for get a list of countries (each time I click on pagination a new request should be made in order to get proper values)

From docs under **controller** section:

> loadData is a function returning an array of data or jQuery promise
>   that will be resolved with an array of data (when pageLoading is true
>   instead of object the structure { data: [items], itemsCount: [total
>   items count] } should be returned). Accepts filter parameter including
>   current filter options and paging parameters when pageLoading is true.

So my PHP function return data in the "proper" format as expected, meaning:

```
{
    data: [items],
    itemsCount: [total items count]
}
```

I have created a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WYL9P97x) with the result I get when the AJAX call is made (for the countries result). I believe the data is right now. So, this is how my code looks like:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/adminconsolejsgrid/subregion"
    }).done(function (subregion) {
        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            height: "70%",
            width: "100%",
            filtering: true,
            sorting: true,
            paging: true,
            autoload: true,
            pageSize: 15,
            pageButtonCount: 5,
            pageLoading: true,
            controller: {
                loadData: function (filter) {
                    return $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/adminconsolejsgrid/countries",
                        data: filter
                    });
                }
            },
            fields: [
                {name: "country_name", title: "Name", type: "text", width: 100, sorting: true},
                {name: "country_abbr", title: "Code", type: "text", width: 5, sorting: true},
                {
                    name: "subregion",
                    title: "SubRegion",
                    type: "select",
                    width: 100,
                    items: subregion,
                    valueField: "subregion_id",
                    textField: "subregion_name"
                },
                {type: "control"}
            ]
        });
    });
});
```

But still not working for me which mean I am not getting any values on the grid. This pic is an example of what I get:

[image]

What I am missing? Any help?

Comment: Are you sure there are no items in the grid? Looks like it's just collapsed. Try to set `height: 400px` to see if the content is empty.

Comment: @tabalin that was the issue, thx